# Update drupal modules without updating core in one drush command

Tags: 7, drush

Is there a way to update all contrib modules without updating core in one drush command.  For example:

`drush up` updates all modules and core.  Is there a way to ignore core and just update the modules without having to list out each module name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `--no-core` flag.

```
drush upc --no-core
```

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/pm/pm-updatecode/